# my python left rotation array code is running okay in IDE by not on HackerRank platform

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to left rotate the array in python by giving the number of rotation I wanted but I'am unable to find the mistake in it
It's perfectly working when I'm trying on jupyter IDE but HackerRank platform is showing wrong answer
my code:

```
def rotateLeft(d, arr):
    for i in range(d):
        temp=arr[0]
        for j in range(len(arr)-1):
            arr[i]=arr[i+1]
        arr[len(arr)-1]=temp    
    return arr
```

[The question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation/problem)
For example

```
input:
5 4
1 2 3 4 5

my output:
2 3 4 2 2
```

which is wrong. Where is the error?

Comment: It's easier to use Python lib - `deque` .  Time to learn the `battery`

Comment: A lib? Stop using libs for every simple thing! check it out my reply, and you will realize how simple is.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easier than you think, have you tried just cuting the array in two parts and concatenate inverting parts again.?

ex> [1,2,3,4]
2 rotate:
[3,4] + [1,2]

result : 3,4,1,2

In python is so easy to do this.

```
def rotateLeft(d, arr):
    return arr[d:] + arr[0:d]
```

This solution have a bug, when the number of rotations are greater than length of the array wont do nothing, so if you calculate the mod of d you can pass it any number.

```
def rotateLeft(d, arr):
    d = d % len(arr)
    return arr[d:] + arr[0:d]
```

Answer (score 0):

The update in the inner loop should use `j` instead of `i`. This should work

```
def rotateLeft(d, arr):
    for i in range(d):
        temp=arr[0]
        for j in range(len(arr)-1):
            arr[j]=arr[j+1]
        arr[len(arr)-1]=temp    
    return arr
```

However, there are simpler solutions to the question. For example the previous answer here.